# Angular BehaviourSubject only being triggered sometimes

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular10

I have a component called Database and a Service (`DatabaseService`).

Then I have a `BehaviourSubject` that has the current database status and I want to get that status on the App Component.

So on the `app.component.ts` I subscribe to the `BehaviourSubject`.

I get the initial value from the BehaviourSubject and I get the value after the `.next()` is called on the database service constructor but if I call `.next()` on the database component I don't get the value on the app component.

I already tried to put the call to the `.next()` on a method inside the database service but it didn't work.

**Database.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-database',
  templateUrl: './database.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./database.component.scss'],
  providers: [DatabaseService]
})


export class DatabaseComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  ...

  constructor(
      private databaseService: DatabaseService,
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    ...
  }

  updateDatabaseStatus(): void {
    this.databaseService.databaseStatus.next(this.StatusId.value);
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    ...
  }
}
```

**database.service.ts**

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
  })
export class DatabaseService {

    public databaseStatus = new BehaviorSubject<DatabaseStatus>(DatabaseStatus.Open);

    constructor(private api: ApiService) {
      this.getSettingsDatabaseStatus().subscribe(data => {
        this.databaseStatus.next(data[0].statusId);
      });
    }

    public getSettingsDatabaseStatus(): Observable<Status> {
      ...
    }

    public updateCurrentDatabaseStatus(status: DatabaseStatus): void {
      this.databaseStatus.next(status);
    }
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {


  public databaseStatus = 'Open';

  constructor(public router: Router,
              private _api: ApiService,
              private databaseService: DatabaseService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.databaseService.databaseStatus.subscribe(status => {
      this.databaseStatus = DatabaseStatus[status];
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you've created more than one instance of the **DatabaseService**.

In your database service the code `providedIn: 'root'` means that a unique instance of that service will be created at the root of your application. i.e. all your components will have access to that instance.

However, in your **database.component** you added the code `providers: [DatabaseService]` which then created a new, unique, local instance of that service that only that component will use.

I'd recommend that you remove that code from your **database.component** and only provide the service at the root level.

Also you definitely want to only call the `.next()` function from the **database service**.

For example your **database.component** code would look like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-database',
  templateUrl: './database.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./database.component.scss']
})


export class DatabaseComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  ...

  constructor(private databaseService: DatabaseService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    ...
  }

  updateDatabaseStatus(): void {
      this.databaseService.updateCurrentDatabaseStatus(this.StatusId.value);
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    ...
  }
}
```

You should be able to leave your **app.component** and **DatabaseService** code the way it is then.

Comment: No problem, happy I could help!